# error Esper XML dom document

Tags: java, xml, dom, runtime-error, esper

I have problems with Esper framework. After searching for a solution, I found an example from official website:

http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.11.0/doc/reference/en-US/html/examples.html#examples-autoid

The source code of this example can be found here:
http://esper.codehaus.org/esper/download/download.html in the examples\autoid dir.

When I run this example I get the following error. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    09:34:07,158 INFO  [EPServiceProviderImpl] Initializing engine URI 'AutoIDSim' version 4.11.0
0 [main] INFO com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl  - Initializing engine URI 'AutoIDSim' version 4.11.0
09:34:07,189 WARN  [XSDSchemaMapper] DOM error reported loading schema from data/AutoIdPmlCore.xsd:
  message: null
  type: null
  related data: null
  related exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
  severity: 3
  location: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMLocatorImpl@3cc433cb
31 [main] WARN com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper  - DOM error reported loading schema from data/AutoIdPmlCore.xsd:
  message: null
  type: null
  related data: null
  related exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
  severity: 3
  location: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMLocatorImpl@3cc433cb
09:34:07,189 WARN  [XSDSchemaMapper] DOM error related exception: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:448)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.setProperty(SchemaParsingConfig.java:492)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.setProperty(SchemaDOMParser.java:503)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reset(XSDHandler.java:3594)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:1068)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:561)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XSLoaderImpl.loadURI(XSLoaderImpl.java:150)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper.readSchemaInternal(XSDSchemaMapper.java:111)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper.loadAndMap(XSDSchemaMapper.java:63)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.init(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:351)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.createServicesContext(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:90)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.doInitialize(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:487)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.<init>(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:89)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProviderInternal(EPServiceProviderManager.java:117)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider(EPServiceProviderManager.java:88)
    at com.espertech.esper.example.autoid.AutoIdSimMain.run(AutoIdSimMain.java:105)
    at com.espertech.esper.example.autoid.AutoIdSimMain.main(AutoIdSimMain.java:77)
31 [main] WARN com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper  - DOM error related exception: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:448)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.setProperty(SchemaParsingConfig.java:492)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.setProperty(SchemaDOMParser.java:503)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reset(XSDHandler.java:3594)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:1068)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:561)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XSLoaderImpl.loadURI(XSLoaderImpl.java:150)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper.readSchemaInternal(XSDSchemaMapper.java:111)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper.loadAndMap(XSDSchemaMapper.java:63)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.init(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:351)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.createServicesContext(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:90)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.doInitialize(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:487)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.<init>(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:89)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProviderInternal(EPServiceProviderManager.java:117)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider(EPServiceProviderManager.java:88)
    at com.espertech.esper.example.autoid.AutoIdSimMain.run(AutoIdSimMain.java:105)
    at com.espertech.esper.example.autoid.AutoIdSimMain.main(AutoIdSimMain.java:77)
09:34:07,189 WARN  [XSDSchemaMapper] DOM error reported loading schema from data/AutoIdPmlCore.xsd:
  message: null
  type: null
  related data: null
  related exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
  severity: 3
  location: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMLocatorImpl@704c98f1
31 [main] WARN com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper  - DOM error reported loading schema from data/AutoIdPmlCore.xsd:
  message: null
  type: null
  related data: null
  related exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
  severity: 3
  location: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMLocatorImpl@704c98f1
09:34:07,189 WARN  [XSDSchemaMapper] DOM error related exception: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:448)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.setProperty(SchemaParsingConfig.java:492)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.setProperty(SchemaDOMParser.java:503)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reset(XSDHandler.java:3594)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:1068)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:561)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XSLoaderImpl.load(XSLoaderImpl.java:168)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper.readSchemaInternal(XSDSchemaMapper.java:124)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper.loadAndMap(XSDSchemaMapper.java:63)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.init(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:351)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.createServicesContext(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:90)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.doInitialize(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:487)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.<init>(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:89)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProviderInternal(EPServiceProviderManager.java:117)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider(EPServiceProviderManager.java:88)
    at com.espertech.esper.example.autoid.AutoIdSimMain.run(AutoIdSimMain.java:105)
    at com.espertech.esper.example.autoid.AutoIdSimMain.main(AutoIdSimMain.java:77)
31 [main] WARN com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper  - DOM error related exception: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:448)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.setProperty(SchemaParsingConfig.java:492)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.setProperty(SchemaDOMParser.java:503)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reset(XSDHandler.java:3594)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:1068)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:561)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XSLoaderImpl.load(XSLoaderImpl.java:168)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper.readSchemaInternal(XSDSchemaMapper.java:124)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.xml.XSDSchemaMapper.loadAndMap(XSDSchemaMapper.java:63)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.init(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:351)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.createServicesContext(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:90)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.doInitialize(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:487)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPServiceProviderImpl.<init>(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:89)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProviderInternal(EPServiceProviderManager.java:117)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider(EPServiceProviderManager.java:88)
    at com.espertech.esper.example.autoid.AutoIdSimMain.run(AutoIdSimMain.java:105)
    at com.espertech.esper.example.autoid.AutoIdSimMain.main(AutoIdSimMain.java:77)
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that Esper doesn't support JRE 1.7 fully, when working with XML and DOM. Installed 1.6 and everything started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with Java 7 update 45, try update 25
See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ESPER-764

Comment: It seems that they have huge problems with versions compatibility in this framework. We installing 1.6 JRE works for me.
P>S
Sorry I can't up your answer - not enought rating :)

Comment: This is a known Java issue that Oracle introduced in JDK7 and is fixed in the newest versions of JVMs.